# Event occuring on no Mouse Move for 3 seconds

Tags: jquery

i have some menus in my script, and i want a jquery script which will cause the menu to hide when no the mouse is not moved for 3 secs..

i know its realy a stupid question, but i cudnt get any answer anywhere..

its not a proper script, but i just want if something happens like it??

```
$("#target").notmousemove(function(event) {
$('#menu').hide();
},delay(500));
```

it wud be highly helpful if someone cud reply my quest..

i have made the menu dissappear on basis on button click, but now i wud rather want the menu to hide when mouse is not moved for more than 5 secs...

Answer (score 9):

Use `setTimeout` in a `mouseMove` handler. If the mouse moves again before the timeout expires, just clear it with `clearTimeout` and restart the timeout again.

So something like:

```
var timeoutid = 0;
$("#someRootElement").mousemove(function() {
    if (timeoutid) {
       clearTimeout(timeoutid);
       timeoutid = 0;
    }
    timeoutid = setTimeout(myFunctionToHideMenu, 5000);
});
```

Edit: in fact, you don't even need to check if the timer is running already. Trying to stop an invalid timer id, or a timer that is already stopped, will cause no errors. So you could just simply to:

```
var timeoutid = 0;
$("#someRootElement").mousemove(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutid);
    timeoutid = setTimeout(myFunctionToHideMenu, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var t;
var delay = 3000; //Ms delay 
$("#target").mousemove(function(){
    clearTimeout(t);

    var t = setTimeout(function(){
        //Has not been moved
        $('#menu').hide();
    }, delay);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function notMouseMove() {
   $("#menu").hide();
}
var timer = setTimeout(notMouseMove, 3000);

$(document).on('mousemove', function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(notMouseMove, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just roll your own plugin:

```
$.fn.notmousemove = function(time, callback) {
    return this.each(function(i,ele) {
        $(ele).on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).data('nomousetimer', setTimeout(callback, time));
            },
            mousemove: function() {
                clearTimeout($(this).data('nomousetimer'));
                $(this).data('nomousetimer', setTimeout(callback, time));
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                clearTimeout($(this).data('nomousetimer'));
            }
        });
    });
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K5U8M/2/)